# Haskell code to compute sum of squares of negative integers using foldr function

Tags: list, haskell, sum, map-function, high-order-component

I am new to haskell code. I tried to compute the sum of squares of negative integer in a list using foldr high order.

```
  sumsq :: Int -> Int
  sumsq n = foldr op 0 [1..n]
  where op x y = x*x + y
```

Please help to explain each line of code and give any solution if error in this code

Comment: What error does it give you (you should always include this; it helps a lot)? Also, what is `op`?

Comment: @David . I have edited my code using foldr func. Please try to help this code

Comment: @Bin Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverFlow is not a homework-writing service.

Comment: What, specifically, are you finding difficult to understand? Which parts of it do you understand and which parts do you not understand? Are you getting any errors? If so, you should copy-and-paste those errors into your question (this is something you should always do, if you are getting errors).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using "where", important to follow the indentation rule.
Here lambda will be appropriate

```
sumsq n = foldr (\x y -> x*x + y) 0 [1..n]
```

Comment: Consider the consequences to StackOverflow when doing people's homework for them. When someone wants each line of code explained, and wants *you* to tell *them* if it has any errors in it, they are not putting any effort in. This is against the purpose of this site and degrades the value of it.